# Display django runserver output from Vagrant guest VM in host Mac notifications?

Tags: python, django, macos, notifications, vagrant

I can think of many ways to skin this cat, and Googling hasn't shown an elegant solution either. Does anyone have an easy / elegant way to forward the output from Django's runserver command in a terminal connected to a guest Vagrant VM to the host to display to Mac's notifications rather than stdout of the guest VM?

On a tiny laptop, screen real estate is at a premium, and flipping terminal windows gets old! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not run a SSH server on the VM and connect from the host via a terminal?  See [MAC SSH](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/how-to-use-ssh-on-mac-os-x/). Which OS is running on the VM? It should not be too hard to get the SSH server installed and running. Of course the VM client OS must have an IP address.